# Gap between search menu and its previous menu on addition of search plugin

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp, jface

I added the Search Plugin to my RCP application. On addition of this plugin it adds the search menu in main menu bar.

I observed that there is some pixels gap between search menu and its previous menu.
Please see the image.

[image]

Does anyone know how this is coming and how I can remove it?

Comment: could you please provide a part of your `plugin.xml` where you add your menu item to the top menubar. Sectioin `menuContribution`.

Comment: I just added "org.eclipse.search" plugin in the dependencies of Meta-INF.
This adds menu contribution in toolbar and menu-bar automatically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this issue by modifying postWindowCreate method of ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class of RCP application.

```
IWorkbenchPage page = this.getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getActivePage();
MenuManager menuBarManager = ((ApplicationWindow)page.getWorkbenchWindow()).getMenuBarManager();
menuBarManager.remove("navigate");
```

Answer (score 2):

Insert a "**navigate**" path in your *ActionBarAdvisor* implementation:

protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {

menuBar.add(createFileMenu());
menuBar.add(createEditMenu());
**menuBar.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.M_NAVIGATE));**
menuBar.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));
menuBar.add(createHelpMenu());

}