# Starting Space in Eclipse coolbar RCP using commands

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have added commands on coolbar of my RCP application from plugin.xml using org.eclipse.ui.menus extension point. When I launch it I get a space in the beginning as shown in the picture below:

[image]

How can i debug this ? I tried adding plugin spy , but its not showing anything there. Interestingly when I add Action contributions there is no space.

plugin.xml snippet adding this command to coolbar :

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
      <menuContribution
            allPopups="false"
            locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar">
         <toolbar
               id="myapp.application.toolbar3">
            <command
                  commandId="myapp.application.setttings.id"
                  icon="icons/3.png"
                  label="Settings"
                  style="push">
            </command>
         </toolbar>
      <toolbar
               id="myapp.application.toolbar1">
            <command
                  commandId="myapp.application.openWizards"
                  icon="icons/5.png"
                  id="myapp.application.openWizards.dropdown"
                  label="Open"
                  mode="FORCE_TEXT"
                  style="pulldown">
            </command>
         </toolbar>

  </menuContribution>
   </extension>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue
[Gap between search menu and its previous menu on addition of search plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14396517/gap-between-search-menu-and-its-previous-menu-on-addition-of-search-plugin/14833362#14833362)

I modified postWindowCreate method of ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor class of my RCP application

Where I debugged, which IContributionItem items are getting added.

```
    IWorkbenchPage page = this.getWindowConfigurer().getWindow().getActivePage();
    MenuManager menuBarManager = ((ApplicationWindow)page.getWorkbenchWindow()).getMenuBarManager();
    IContributionItem[] items = menuBarManager.getItems();
    // iterate on items and its children and see which contribution item is getting added 
    // if any unwanted items are present the remove it
```